# How to execute python subprocess.Popen() via "SYSTEM" user in windows

Tags: python, windows, shell, automation, access-rights

I am using python script to start java spring boot web service
Here is my code

```
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("java -jar webService.jar", shell=True)
```

I want this process to run via "SYSTEM" user in windows, is there any proper way to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273939/python-subprocess-popen-as-different-user-on-windows
See if this solves your issue

Comment: Although it is a bad idea to run scripts as the SYSTEM user you can run java from Windows Scheduler. The default user for tasks is SYSTEM.